# Median of two different sized sorted arrays

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, quicksort, median

I'm trying to find the median of two different sized sorted arrays. But there are a few situations where it doesn't work and I wasn't able to figure out why. I've included my implementation below.

I do realize there are similar solutions online. But I'm just starting to learn algorithms and so want to do as much as possible by myself. Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

```
public double median(Point[] arr, int start, int end) {
    int n = end - start + 1;
    if (n % 2 == 0) {
        return (double) (arr[start + (n/2)].getSz() + arr[start + (n/2) - 1].getSz())/2;
    }
    else {
        return (double) arr[start + (n/2)].getSz();
    }
}

public double getMedian(int aStart, int aEnd, int bStart, int bEnd) {
    int m = aEnd - aStart + 1;
    int n = bEnd - bStart + 1;
    double median = 0;

    if (m == 0 && n > 0) {
        return median(arr2, 0, bEnd);
    }

    if (m > 0 && n == 0) {
        return median(arr1, 0, aEnd);
    }

    if (m == 1 && n == 1) {
        return (double) (arr1[0].getSz() + arr2[0].getSz())/2;
    }

    if (m == 2 && n == 2) {
        median = (double) (Math.max(arr1[aStart].getSz(), arr2[bStart].getSz()) + Math.min(arr1[aEnd].getSz(), arr2[bEnd].getSz()))/2;
        return median;
    }

    double m1 = median(arr1, aStart, aEnd);
    double m2 = median(arr2, bStart, bEnd);

    if (m1 == m2) {
        return m1;
    }

    if (m1 < m2) {
        if (m % 2 == 0) {
            aStart = aStart + (m/2) - 1;
            index = 1;
        }
        else {
            index = 2;
            aStart = aStart + m/2;
        }
        bEnd = bStart + n/2;
    }
    else {
        if (n % 2 == 0) {
            index = 3;
            bStart = bStart + n/2 - 1;
        }
        else {
            index = 4;
            bStart = bStart + n/2;
        }
        aEnd = aStart + m/2;
    }
    return (getMedian(aStart, aEnd, bStart, bEnd));
}
```

Here's a example for which the logic breaks:
arr1 = 6, 20, 28, 29, 36, 41
arr2 = 14, 25, 33, 47, 53, 66, 79, 98

Correct median = 34.5
Estimated median = 31

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there are a few problems in the algorithm.

Firstly 0 is being used instead of aStart and bStart in a couple of places:

```
   if (m == 0 && n > 0) {
        return median(arr2, ->0<-, bEnd);
    }

    if (m > 0 && n == 0) {
        return median(arr1, ->0<-, aEnd);
    }

    if (m == 1 && n == 1) {
        return (double) (arr1[->0<-].getSz() + arr2[->0<-].getSz())/2;
    }
```

Secondly; in the last block you must be careful to throw out as many values above the median as below it.

```
if (m1 < m2) {
    if (m % 2 == 0) {
        aStart = aStart + (->m<-/2) - 1;
        index = 1;
    }
    else {
        index = 2;
        aStart = aStart + ->m<-/2;
    }
    bEnd = bStart + ->n<- /2;
}
```

and also you must not throw out the values closest to the median where the median is calculated on an even number of data.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes this helps a lot! Works perfectly now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

To get the median of two sorted arrays **A** and **B**, you need to figure out how to split both arrays into a low part and a high part, so that all the low part elements are <= all the high part elements, and the total number of elements in the low and high parts are the same (within 1).

The low elements will consist of some number **x** of elements from **A**, and **(A.length + B.length)/2 - x** elements from **B**.

To find **x**, you do a binary search on the possible values of **x**.  Let **MID=(A.length + B.length)/2**.   Then, given a guess at **x**, if **A[x-1]>B[MID-x]** then **x** is too big.  Otherwise it is not too big.  That condition is enough to allow you to reduce the range of values by half in each iteration.

Once you know where the arrays are divided, you know that **max(A[x-1],B[MID-x-1])** is the highest element in the low parts, and **min(A[x],B[MID-x])** is lowest element in the high parts, and that is all you need to calculate the median.